# Setting secret credentials when using Golang Test Explorer or automated test runner

Tags: go, testing, api-key

I am working on some unit tests for some functions that require API credentials to upload and list files in a DigitalOcean Spaces bucket. Thee values have already been set using CLI flags. I am using Go Test Explorer to run the tests, and I noticed that those two tests fail due to the credentials being empty. Does anyone know if there is a way to set envars in a test without having to explicitly set them in the commmand line before executing "go test -run"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`go 1.17` just added the ability to change environment variables for the duration of a test via [T.Setenv](https://golang.org/doc/go1.17#testing).

From the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/testing#T.Setenv):

> T.Setenv calls os.Setenv(key, value) and uses Cleanup to restore the
> environment variable to its original value after the test.
>
> This cannot be used in parallel tests.

Example Usage:

```
func getCreds() (u, p string) {
    u, p = os.Getenv("USER"), os.Getenv("PASS")
    return
}

func TestEnv(t *testing.T) {
    t.Setenv("USER", "xxx")
    t.Setenv("PASS", "yyy")

    u, p := getCreds()
    t.Logf("creds: %q / %q", u, p) // will get local testing env settings
}

func TestNoEnv(t *testing.T) {

    u, p := getCreds()
    t.Logf("creds: %q / %q", u, p) // will get nothing
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/QBl3hV6WjWA

---

***EDIT***: from the comments it appears that your (or DigialOcean's) test functions use `FlagSet` which is command line options (might be helpful if you shared some of the test code in the question). Anyway if this is the case, the correct way to invoke a `go test` and pass arguments is like so:

```
go test -args -spaces-key="KEY" -spaces-secret="S3CR3T"
```

If you want to pass ENV VARs then the way you were doing before was correct:

```
SCOREKEEPER_SPACES_KEY="key" SCOREKEEPER_SPACES_SECRET="s3cr3t" go test
```

Comment: Thanks so much for that! Awesome answer, I'm successfully able to t.Logf() the creds I set with t.SetEnv(), but for some reason they are not setting and I'm getting the following error response from DOSpaces: "EmptyStaticCreds: static credentials are empty"

Comment: Can you post more details on how you are running the test? Does the `DO` credential check actually pull its values from env vars?

Comment: SCOREKEEPER_SPACES_KEY="keyvalue" SCOREKEEPER_SPACES_SECRET="secretvalue" go test -timeout 30s -run ^TestListAllFilesInDOSpace$ --count=1 -v

So that is how I am running it manually to get a successful response. But DO is grabbing them from envars

I set them with flags in the command line. They are parsed in variables in my main file containing these two functions and others like below:

var (
 spacesKey    = config.FlagSet.String("spaces-key", "", "DO spaces key")
 spacesSecret = config.FlagSet.String("spaces-secret", "", "DO spaces secret")
)

Comment: Apparently those flags are not actually set in test mode in Go to the best of my knowledge. So I was trying to simulate it to get some properly working tests by doing something like what you suggested above, but something is still amiss.

Comment: Gotcha! I double checked, everything appears good. So weird lol. Everything else works exactly as you described above. I can see the cred values in terminal after running test.

Comment: Do you know if there is anything I may need to do before the go test command would normally execute? Seems like this should attach envars automatically

Comment: Updated answer to reflect passing flag or ENV VAR arguments via the command-line.